# jquery POST does not return any result in https

Tags: php, jquery, post, ssl, https

I have a jquery script that just runs fine on http://mysite.com

and looks like this:

Javascript:

```
$('#form_changePass').live('submit', function() {
    //alert('form_changePass cliked');
    $.POST("_ajaxCall.php", $(this).serialize(),
    function(data){
        var json = eval('('+data+')');
        //alert(data);    
        if(json.message=='alert') {
            $('div.info').hide();
            $('div.alert').show().html(json.string);
        }
        if(json.message=='info') {
            $('div.alert').hide();
            $('div.info').show().html(json.string);
        }
    }
    );
    return false;
})
```

PHP script:

```
if ($_POST['formType']=="form_changePass") {
.....
.......
   $arr = array( 'message' => 'info', 'string' => $INFO['updatePass']);
   echo json_encode($arr);
}
```

Now when I move the domain into https the jquery script is not working anymore. I do not get any return value back. Nothing happens.

I also tried to change the POST to getJSON in the javascript and changed the $_POST to $_GET in the php script but it is still not working.

Anybody a idea?

Comment: Does `$.POST` work? That should be lowercase!

Comment: Are you including jQuery over https as well?

Comment: $.POST was a typo, I use $.post.

Comment: I am loading jQuery with a path variable in front. example /var/www/http/js/jquery.js. Also tried the full https url without luck.

Comment: Can you see any redirected requests in Firefox or Chrome dev tools, or perhaps with HTTPFox? Do basic GETs on your `https://` site work as expected?

Comment: Yes I can, all my POST requests are send via https

Answer (score 1):

http and https are considered different domains, so it is a cross domain issue. The fix is:

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: https://domain.com');
```

Add this to your php script. Or this only in development so you don't need to worry too much:

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
```

Answer (score -1):

`.serialize` serializes the form data as a string, so send them using a parameter instead.

```
$('#form_changePass').on('submit', function() {
    //alert('form_changePass cliked');
    $.POST("_ajaxCall.php", { formData: $(this).serialize() },
    function(data){
        var json = eval('('+data+')');
        //alert(data);    
        if(json.message=='alert') {
            $('div.info').hide();
            $('div.alert').show().html(json.string);
        }
        if(json.message=='info') {
            $('div.alert').hide();
            $('div.info').show().html(json.string);
        }
    }
    );
    return false;
})
```

And stop using `.live()` methods, they have been deprecated now. Use `.on()` methods.

Comment: Do you have a reputable source for "Its preferred that you send the serialized data using a parameter instead."?

Comment: @AnthonyGrist, Yeah I read an article about it, am trying to find it. If not I will edit the answer :)

Comment: What's the point of sending `formData` argument with serialized form data? How it may help to solve the problem?

Comment: @VisioN, I dont understand your concern about the What and How? The point is for the data to be accessible under a variable, and by making it a valid POST request, it solves the problem.

Comment: @Starx Please read the [jQuery docs](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/) carefully: _data - a map or **string** that is sent to the server with the request_. And also have a look at the example #4 under the same link.

Comment: @VisioN, I know the point you are trying to make, but I can't find an live code, which is using the OP's method. Can you point me one?